# Ros can't find dependency for OpenCV2

Tags: opencv, ros

I am using the tutorial on [this webpage](https://siddhantahuja.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/working-with-ros-and-opencv-draft/) to learn how to work with ROSand OpenCV. This tutorial uses ROS fuerte but I am using ROS indigo. I changed the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-camera-umd
```

to

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-camera-umd
```

At the stage of creating a new package for image processing, I typed in this command in the command window:

```
maurice@maurice-OptiPlex-9020:~$ roscreate-pkg tutorialROSOpenCV > image_transport roscpp std_msgs opencv2 cv_bridge uvc_camera
```

However I get the following error:

```
maurice@maurice-OptiPlex-9020:~$ roscreate-pkg tutorialROSOpenCV image_transport roscpp std_msgs opencv2 cv_bridge uvc_camera
```

One of the comments in the webpage did raise this question but I am unable to locate the OpenCV folder.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had the same problem using OpenCV2 and I'll let another one to get a solution for that. What I recommend you to do is using the `catkin_create_pkg` command to create your package. So, the full command will become:

```
catkin_create_pkg tutorialROSOpenCV image_transport roscpp std_msgs opencv2 cv_bridge uvc_camera
```

and hopefully, you'll get it working.

Also, there's a lot of tutorials on using OpenCV2 with ROS using catkin starting with [this one](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages).

The downside of this solution (and somehow the upside of it) is that you have to work with CMakeLists.txt and Package.xml as the catkin conventions, not the RosBuild ones (e.g. use `add_executable` instead of `rosbuild_add_executable`, see full list of migration instructions [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild)).

Also there's always the ROS Answers [forum](http://answers.ros.org/questions/) to help with the issues and the ROS [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/) for starting guides.

Cheers,